# Disk is full and now I can't boot into Ubuntu

Tags: boot, ssd, disk-usage

I was syncing photos and videos from my phone using SyncThing onto my laptop running Ubuntu 20.04.1.
The local SSD (/dev/sda2) was completely full so after copying to an external hard disk drive I deleted them from the local drive by pressing the `delete` key on the keyboard. I did not empty the trash afterwards.

Some time after that I restarted the machine. Now, instead of successfully booting it got to a message

```
/dev/sda2: clean, 367601/15597568 files, 59266164/6238360 blocks
```

My guess is somehow that the filesystem is so full, that the OS is unable to do what it needs to do to successfully boot.

So I booted using the Live USB that I had originally installed from, hoping to fix the issue. Once inside the live session I was hoping to do some kind of scan or delete some files to free up space on the local SSD. Unfortunately I do no have permissions to modify the SSD contents.

Any suggestions as to what I should try?

Edit: I also saw a message along the lines of

```
initramfs decoding failed: unpacking failed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my own problem with the following method.

1. Boot from Live USB (I used the one that I originally installed my local OS from but probably any Linux live drive would work.
2. Open a terminal.
3. Make a new directory, let's say `mnt`. `mkdir mnt`
4. Mount the local drive. `mount /dev/sda2 mnt`
5. Call `sudo -H nautilus .` and then from the Nautilus graphical interface I deleted a large file with <kbd>Delete</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd>. It asked for confirmation.
6. Since the file was deleted without going to trash, I assumed that there was now some free space and rebooted.

Voila. I am now able to boot into the OS again.

Comment: **`sudo nautilus` is not recommended**, I got a few downvotes last time I mentioned it in an answer. It has to do with permissions being changed. Better to use `sudo -H nautilus` or better yet  install `nautilus-admin` and use that. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/604011/difference-between-nautilus-and-sudo-nautilus

Comment: Thanks, I think I did actually use `sudo -H nautilus`, so will update the answer.

Comment: I needed to do `sudo mount /dev/sda2 mnt` to get this to work for me.

Answer (score 5):

You only need to boot Ubuntu in **Advanced Options For Ubuntu**.

[image: GRUB menu]

Select an option with **recovery mode**

Then select the **Clean - Try to make free space** option.

[image: Recovery mode options]

Now, Select **Resume - resume normal boot**

Your computer will boot up with just enough space to clean it up fully.

Comment: Hello. This may or may not work depending on how much space is freed up. Your last statement should reflect that.

Comment: What does this option actually try in order to free up space? Presumably it empties the trash/recycle bin and removes some temporary files. 
It sounds like a good thing to try first in most cases. However, as @David mentioned, it might not work for everyone, say if the trash is already empty.