# Can’t boot because of full disk

Tags: crash, disk-usage

So Ubuntu did not start with me because the disk was full, don’t know how tbh-
I started Ubuntu in recovery mode and removed lost and found folder and rebooted the whole system again.
Unfortunately it seems like that did not fix the issue and my drive is still full,
I don’t know what is taking such a space and I can’t seem to install anything
I ran df and this what came up.
Any help would be appreciated.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGmbU.jpg)

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1295288/disk-is-full-and-now-i-cant-boot-into-ubuntu

Answer (score 2):

Boot from usb-stick the 'live'-environment. Search for temporary files (also package chaches and application caches (firefox e.g. caches a lot) and your waste bin) on the harddisk and remove them. Speaks for itself that you don´t remove the waste bin but empty it.

Comment: lost+found != trash. The lost+found directory is a construct used by the fsck system utility. It’s a special directory that contains data that has become obsolete. The fsck utility creates it on a Linux machine with partitions of the Extended File System (ext2-ext4). However, they’re also created on other file systems like UFS and ZFS on UNIX derivatives.

The fsck utility creates the lost+found directory at the root of a volume. So, we can have multiple lost+found directories – one for each of the volumes.

Comment: Yes. And it is locked by default. Can be accesed as root.

Comment: So I tried running Ubuntu from the usb drive but I still can’t remove anything. 
I tried using Sudo but it won’t let me.

Comment: is your volume mounted as read-only? https://askubuntu.com/questions/175739/how-do-i-remount-a-filesystem-as-read-write

Comment: Thanks a lot, One of the users filled his desktop with 300gb worth of files, once I deleted his account and all his files everything went back to normal.