# Can't switch keyboard layout in terminal (Lubuntu 20.04)

Tags: command-line, 20.04, lubuntu, language-support, layout

I am using a bilingual version of Lubuntu 20.04.
In virtual console the primary layout should be English, but I can't switch language to English - it is always secondary one so virtual console is unusable.
I googled and tried all possible hot keys for it. And I installed all last updates.

How to fix this problem?

Right now I need to fix my system, it can't boot because no space left, and most advises are about virtual console.

P.S. I've tried this:

1. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCdRecovery
2. [Disk is full and now I can't boot into Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1295288/disk-is-full-and-now-i-cant-boot-into-ubuntu/1295296#1295296)

Comment: Lubuntu 20.04 LTS is now EOL (see https://lubuntu.me/lubuntu-20-04-lts-end-of-life-and-current-support-statuses/) but please note it's still on-topic here. If you're using 20.04.1 then you're years behind on applying security fixes, as a fully upgraded 20.04 system has reported itself at 20.04.6 for some time (see https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/03/23/ubuntu-20-04-6-lts-released/ for ISO release date, but installed systems upgraded in the week before that; upgrading to 20.04.2 back in 2021 yet your system hasn't received that yet?).  You need to fix space problems at terminal though

Comment: To switch keyboard layout in a virtual console, try: `sudo loadkeys us`

Answer (score -1):

If you're talking about the virtual console tty:  no, that has nothing to do with your graphic session, the keyboard layout is set in `$ cat /etc/vconsole.conf  KEYMAP=de`

Comment: AFAIK that file is not present on Ubuntu including Lubuntu.

Comment: Yes, I meant virtual console.

I've check vconsole.conf, it is set to us one (KEYMAP=us), but can't type in English there.

Also I checked it on 22.04, it's similar to 20.04, but virtuale console is working fine there, English is default.

Comment: @crt_tim5: I see. Then disregard my comment.