# Black screen after logging in

Tags: lubuntu, nautilus, disk-usage

Lubuntu 20.04.

Having black screen after logging in, probably because of lack of free space in root.
Usually I used this solution in this case before, but it doesn't work now:

- [Disk is full and now I can't boot into Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1295288/disk-is-full-and-now-i-cant-boot-into-ubuntu/1295296#1295296)

Also in live USB mode I tried to mount it and chroot there, cleaned and uninstalled some apps.
File managers still show 0 bytes free. On another hand, Gparted shows me space I freed correctly(more than 5 Gbs unused).

**N.B.** Unfortunately I can't use virtual console because of a bug.

Any other solutions please?

Comment: FYI:  You're aware that Lubuntu 20.04 LTS was a *flavor* of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and came with 3 years of supported life? (refer https://lubuntu.me/lubuntu-20-04-lts-end-of-life-and-current-support-statuses/ reaching the end of its three year supported life) with 5 years applying to Ubuntu Desktop, Ubuntu Server, Ubuntu base but not *flavors*. You're still on-topic here with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS questions though (*even if using LXQt*)

Answer (score 0):

from recovery mode reinstall your file manager,
exit from recovery mode `exit` and choose the first menu entry to login to ubuntu

Comment: `nautilus`?   It won't be installed for re-installed (*on a default Lubuntu install*) and will require a load of *depends* to be pulled in (given Lubuntu is a Qt5 environment using the LXQt desktop; nautilus is the GNOME file manager and relies on GTK toolkits/libraries).  Are you sure this is helpful?   Lack of disk space was mentioned; yet you're wanting to use more disk space?

Comment: @guiverc sorry I meant his file manager

Comment: The LXQt file-manager program is `pcmanfm-qt`, which also handles some of the desktop itself.. so it's a rather critical app. I'm not sure re-installing it will help (esp. if disk space issues exist) with as I understand it the file-manager was run from *live* system (thus it works) and GUI login won't proceed if no space exists on $HOME on the installed system...  Yes the OP tagged `nautilus` for a reason I don't understand (it's **not** a Lubuntu provided app) but I'd fix space issue at terminal.. alas 20.04 is EOL as far as Lubuntu is concerned.

Comment: as he said "File managers still show 0 bytes free. On another hand, Gparted shows me space I freed correctly(more than 5 Gbs unused)". so I suggest reinstall file manager may be a solution .